# installation fail with 'pip install brightway2': for offline installation

Tags: brightway

I hope you guys are safe and well.

For context, i have been using brightway from the conda install, which works perfectly.

However when i try to install using `pip install brightway2` after creating a new environment, i cannot run jupyter notebooks neither can i run the python interpreter using `ipython`. I get the following error:`'ipython' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` I also tried doing `pip install pywin32` since I am using windows.

The reason i am looking for pip install, is so that i can use `pip download brightway2` to install it offline on a server for some calculations.

I am a novice in computer sciences, so do you guys have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around this to install brightway2 offline - if anyone is interested.

After activating the environment, First, I created a file of all the required packages (in the computer where brightway2 is already installed) using:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then I downloaded these packages using:

```
pip download -r requirement.txt -d /some_folder
```

After copying the dowloaded files to the server, I ran the following:

```
pip install -r requirements1.txt --no-index --find-links=file:///local/dir
```

There was one file which was problematic (it could not be downloaded), the package  [pypardiso](https://github.com/haasad/PyPardisoProject). But I discovered it can be downloaded [here](https://anaconda.org/haasad/pypardiso/files) and installed offline using conda 
`conda install ///path_to/brightway_files/pypardiso-0.2.2-py_0.tar.bz2`